# Relation between $\phi$ and $\pi$

Tags: calculus, pi, golden-ratio

I saw this $$\frac  65 \phi^2 \sim \pi$$ with $99.9985\%$ of accuracy. There are many more estimations like this between $\phi $ and $\pi$, I think?!. Now the question is about the origination of this(those) estimation. Is it a geometrical representation of this concept?
can someone get a clue?

Comment: Not just $\phi$ and $\pi$, but all kinds of unrelated irrational numbers have "close matches" when you allow powers and multiplication by rational numbers. Moreover all such operations can be represented geometrically, but if you do not have an exact equation, how is that representation meaningful to you?

Comment: @DavidK: It was intersting to me because pi an phi are irrational, but say 99.9985 of acuracy. (truncation maybe used).Honestly I found it on web. I checked it by calculator. But  I can't find a representation about it.

Comment: Any irrational number can be approximated arbitrarily closely by rational numbers. Suppose the ratio $\phi/\pi$ is irrational. You can still set $m\phi \approx n\pi$ for integers $m$ and $n$ to any degree of accuracy you want. By chance, for some pairs of irrational numbers the numbers $m$ and $n$ will be small. I don't think the meaning is any deeper than that.

Comment: It is very likely that this is just a coincidence.

Comment: @DavidK You don’t need to suppose $\phi/ \pi$ is irrational, it is irrational since $\pi$ is transcendental.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku Yes, we know this ratio is irrational, but I'm making a more general argument that applies to any pair of irrational numbers, not just $\phi$ and $\pi.$

Comment: There are numerical coincidences all over the place in mathematics (there is even a short [Wikipedia article on this topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_integer)).  Expecting there to be something more than coincidence feels like numerology, to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are exact equivalences of $\pi^3$ using $\phi$ [derived in this short paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2206.15281.pdf). It states that $$\pi^3=\frac{125}{4}\frac{(3-\phi)^{3/2}}{\phi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{(1-5n)^3}$$and $$\pi^3=\frac{250}{\phi^3\sqrt{2+\phi}}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{(1-10n)^3}$$ Take a look at this integral $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+2x+5}dx=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{\phi}}$$[From this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1029506/evaluating-int-0-infty-frac-sqrtxx22x5-dx-using-complex-analysis/1029631#1029631). Here is another identity: $$\frac1{12}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{x\,dx}{\phi-\cos^2 x}=\frac{\pi^2}6$$

Comment: nice solution, (+1)

Comment: @SineoftheTime I didn't see your comment. Thanks! Also, congratulations for getting two gold badges!

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the [golden triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_triangle_%28mathematics%29) could allow for some geometric intuition.

You can use the cosine law on the golden triangle to show that
$$
\frac{6}{5}\phi^2=\frac{3}{5(1-\cos(\frac{\pi}{5}))}\approx\pi.
$$

As a side note, if you notice that $\cos(\frac{\pi}{5})=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4}=\frac{1}{2}\phi$, we arrive at
$$
\phi^2=\frac{1}{2-\phi}.
$$

Answer (score 4):

There are a vast combination of real numbers $a,p,q$ such that $a\phi^p\pi^q\approx 1$. You have found the example $a=6/5~,~p=2~,~q=-1$. But there are others, like $a=111/250~,p=q=1/2$. So one might ask

> I have seen that $\frac{111}{250}\sqrt{\phi}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ to within less than a 1% error. Why???

Because.... numbers??

Comment: But how can I find $p,q$ here ?

Comment: @Khosrotash The same way I found my example - by trial and error. The whole point of my answer is that there is nothing special about the example you found.

Answer (score -1):

This can be interpreted by the fact that the area of an inscribed [regular decagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decagon#Regular_decagon) is *close to the area of the disk* and that the side of the regular decagon $a$ and the radius of the circle are linked by the formula:
$$R= a \phi.$$

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. The number $6$ is nowhere in sight, whether we consider area or perimeter, inscribed or circumscribed.

Comment: Given a regular decagon's circumradius $R$, the inradius is $r=R\cos(\pi/10)=\tfrac12R\sqrt{\varphi\sqrt5}$, and the edge length is $a=2R\sin(\pi/10)=R\varphi^{-1}$. The decagon's perimeter is $10a=10R\varphi^{-1}$, and its area is $20(\tfrac14ar)=\tfrac52R^2\sqrt{\varphi^{-1}\sqrt5}$. The inscribed circle's perimeter is $2\pi r=\pi R\sqrt{\varphi\sqrt5}$, and its area is $\pi r^2=\tfrac14\pi R^2\varphi\sqrt5$. The circumscribed circle's perimeter is $2\pi R$, and its area is $\pi R^2$. How do you get $\tfrac65\varphi^2$ from any of this?

Comment: @amWhy No thanks. I'm happy, and also free by the way, to spend my time where I want to.

Comment: @mr_e_man: Thank you for clarifying.